Question about a statement in a paper regarding convergence in distribution
I'm confused about a line in a paper I'm reading. The author says,
"In such a scenario, given estimates $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\Omega}_{\beta}$ such that $\hat{\beta}\overset{p}{\to}\beta$ and $\hat{\Omega}_{\beta}\overset{p}{\to}\Omega_{\beta}$, where $\Omega_{\beta}$ is positive semidefinite, then estimates of $\Theta$ and $\Omega_{\Theta}$ can be obtained from
$$min_{\Theta}Q(\Theta)=min_{\theta}(\hat{\beta}-\phi(\Theta))'\hat{\Omega}_{\beta}^{-1}(\hat{\beta}-\phi(\Theta))$$
where $\hat{\Theta}\overset{p}{\to}\Theta$ and $\sqrt{T-H}(\hat{\Theta}-\Theta)\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,\Omega_{\theta})$, where $T$ and $H$ are positive numbers.
My questions is about the last sentence about converging in distribution to a normal. How is that possible if $\hat{\Theta}$ converges to $\Theta$ in probability? Shouldn't it converge to $0$ in distribution?

It's not clear what limit is involved in this scenario - is there some underlying parameter $n$ going to $\infty$ or the like? Anyway, if $T$ and $H$ are fixed then indeed it seems strange, but if they also depend on the underlying parameter and $\sqrt{T-H}$ is diverging, then it could be fine?

Suppose $X_n=3+Z/\sqrt{n}$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Then we have $X_n$ converging to $3$ in probability and also $\sqrt n (X_n-3)$ converging in distribution to $N(0,1)$.  The way $\sqrt n$ slips into the formula shows the second convergence statement is more detailed than the first: not only is $X_n$ very close to $3$, it differs from $3$ by something of order $1/\sqrt n$.

The comment by @NicholasBurbank is on point, without further context on what $T$ and $H$ are, and whether they go to infinity etc. makes it difficult to answer your question. Anyhow, I'll give you another counterexample to your claim, assuming that $n:= T-H \to\infty$. Suppose that you have i.i.d. observations $X_{i} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$. Then by the law of large numbers you have as $n\to\infty$ that $\hat{\mu} := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} \overset{p}{\to} \mu$, but by the CLT you have $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu} - \mu) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^{2})$.
